# Find missing values in timeseries

Tags: r

I have a time series data.
I need to find missing values in a time series data and display it back to the user. I just need an algorithm that will run fast. Since this output needs to be generated in Shiny. Can't keep the user waiting for long

```
# creating sample data
topdays <- seq(1,6,2)
topobs <- rep("Adams",3)
middays <- rep(seq(1:6),3)
midobs <- c(rep("Allen",6),rep("Benton",6),rep("Blackford",6))
bottomdays <- seq(1,6,2)
bottomobs <- rep("Brown",3)
values <- runif(24, min=70, max=100)
obs <- c(topobs,midobs,bottomobs)
days <- c(topdays,middays,bottomdays)
df <- data.frame(days,values,obs)
# end creation of sample data
```

As you see there is data missing for observations Adams and Brown at day 2,4,6.

I want to create a function where i capture the missing day and the observation

The output should create a data frame with  missing value and its observation.

I have just created a sample of my problem statement.

The real dataset will be very big.

Thanking you in anticipation for have looked at this.
Let me know if I can provide some more details

Comment: Please see `?is.na`

Comment: I am afraid I did not get you

Comment: type `?is.na` into the R command prompt - then read the help page.

Comment: In the dataset I have created there are no NA's

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want the output to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we could try:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
setkeyv(df, c("days", "obs"))
df[with(df, expand.grid(unique(days), unique(obs)))][is.na(values)]
```

output

```
   days values   obs
1:    2     NA Adams
2:    4     NA Adams
3:    6     NA Adams
4:    2     NA Brown
5:    4     NA Brown
6:    6     NA Brown
```

Comment: This runs fine when I run it in rstudio.
There is an error when running it in shiny.
I get the following error:
Error in .subset(x, i) : invalid subscript type 'list'.

Comment: Is there a diffferent approach to this